# Finding the sum of an infinite power series with formula summation.

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, power-series

So I learned a formula which says that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n= \frac{1}{1-x}$ which it can be used in fact to determine a sum of a power series.

I have this exercise to determine the sum:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {x^{2n}}{2n}$$ for $|x| <1 $.

The answer given in the book is $-\frac 12 \cdot \ln(1-x^2)$.

But when I calculated, I got $2\ln|x| + \frac{1}{1-x}$.

Could you help me please, I would appreciate it very much. Thanks!

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

An alternative method:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2n}}{2n}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int x^{2n-1}dx=\int \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^{2n-1}dx=\int\frac{x}{1-x^2}dx=-\frac{1}{2}log(1-x^2)$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

$$y=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {x^{2n}}{2n}\implies y'=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^{2n-1}=\frac 1x \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^{2n}=\frac 1x \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (x^2)^n$$

Comment: So, basically, i did the same thing i guess. I mean,i squared the equation, i divided it by x on both sides, and after that i integrated it. Isn't that the point?

Comment: Oh wait, i can substitute x by xsquared in the initial formula...

Comment: @VladGabriel. It seems that you got it ! Cheers :-)

Comment: Thank you very much man :) I really appreciate :D

Comment: @VladGabriel. I am glad to know that I helped ! By the way, *Welcome to the site !*

Comment: Thank you.. uhm, sory for that.. i also got stuck in a wrong result after further calculations. I mean, after i integrate y i get (1/x  *  1 / (1-x^2) ) inside the integral. Like the response of @potassiumcyanide but with the x below, multiplied with the denominator... :(

Comment: @VladGabriel. You are supposed to find $y'=\frac1 x \times \frac {x^2}{1-x^2}=\frac x{1-x^2}$. You sum from $n=1$ not $n=0$

Comment: Okay, so basically, the first formula which appears in my post, the one standardised for x=0 to inf, is not the same with *n=1 to inf*?

Comment: Yeah, i am dumb.. :) It is actually x^1 + x^2 +... = x ( x^0 + x^1 +... )